# Constant curvature geodesic circles on a surface with constant Gauss curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, curvature, geodesic

Referring to: [Curvature of geodesic circles on surface with constant curvature](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162474/curvature-of-geodesic-circles-on-surface-with-constant-curvature),

Is it possible to combine further the last two of the three equations in the link given above into a single ODE / PDE to obtain constant geodesic curvature = 1/b?

Aim is to get an equation for u = constant "circles" or loops on surface of constant Gauss curvature K = 1/a^2, ( b not equal to a ) in geodesic polar coordinates in general.

Or, is the last equation alone adequate to define the boundary for all constant K surfaces?

I attempted to numerically find a solution in a procedure that computes constant geodesic curvature in case of constant K surfaces of revolution, positive and negative K, am attaching what might serve as a representative image:

http://i58.tinypic.com/2mm7o06.jpg

( Found an error after uploading: T is actually the radius of curvature = 1/kg).

" J-circle " is nomenclature from an old Russian book that I cannot readily find again.

However, I look for a general formulation that removes restriction on surfaces of revolution.

Regards

I also like to know if the line kg= const on K = const surface is always a closed loop/ oval.

Comment: Please clarify the question. Combine *what*?  As it stands, the readers have to look at two pages at once to figure out what you are asking about. (And at least to me, even that did not help.)

Comment: @900sit-upsaday.  Combine two inputs of constant kg and constant gauss curvature K to obtain one resulting equation containing these two scalar quantities.