# Gauss Bonnet theorem validation with hyperbolic circles

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

How to verify the theorem in case of a hyperbolic circle radius $r$ for constant negative Gauss curvature $ K=-1/a^2 $ and constant geodesic curvature $k_g $ ...
 e.g., [like here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911372/ovals-of-constant-k-g-on-constant-k-surfaces)...

$$k_g=1/r \tag1 $$

$$  \int k_g ds + \int\int K dA = 2 \pi \tag2 $$

(Geodesic polar coordinates) [Perimeter and Area](http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/wws/cabripages/hyperbolic/circleformulae.html) plugged in from :

$$ Perimeter = 2 \pi a \sinh (r/a) ,\, Area= 4 \pi a^2 \sinh^2(r/2a) \tag3 $$

as these reduce to $ ( 2\pi r, \pi r^2) $ when $ a\rightarrow \infty$

$$\frac{\pi a \sinh (r/a)   }{ r } -{ 4 K \pi a^2 \sinh^2 (r/2a)} = 2 \pi $$

does not tally in general. Also when $ r\rightarrow 0,  \pi + \pi (r/a)^2 \ne 2 \pi$

Clearly (1) is assumed intentionally wrong, but then what is correct ? It needs to be defined  properly in the tangent plane or in the hyperbolic plane which is not known to me.

Since a direct calculation (like for case $ K=+1/a^2 $)  appears elusive.. an indirect back -calculation is the only resort . For this case we have after some simplification:

$$  \boxed{a \, k_g= \coth (r/a ), R_g=a \tanh (r/a)}\tag4$$

verified by plugging this into GB thm (1). When

$$r\rightarrow \infty,\,k_g \rightarrow \,(1/a),\, R_g \rightarrow \,a \tag5 $$

$$r=0 ,k_{g} = \infty \tag6 $$

as expected for a point circle.

(4) is a new result (for me) surprising and apparently anomalous because it is bounded. There is *no way to check it directly or conceptually* reinforcing it by other theorems or better known results in hyperbolic geometry.

And that is the motivation of this posting...

Show **how theses hyperbolic circles are/can be placed geometrically in the hyperbolic models** available (Poincaré half plane, Poincaré disc and Klein's )

Comment: What value are you using for $k_g$, and how do you justify that value?

Comment: I am unable to calculate here. For sphere $K=+1/a^2$ it is easy

Comment: That's a source of error, then. You cannot just pick the formula $k_g=1/r$ out of a hat and hope that it is the correct formula; although it may be correct in the Euclidean plane, it is wrong in the hyperbolic plane. On the other hand, you could use the Gauss-Bonnet theorem to *calculate* a formula for $k_g$ (which should depend on $r$ and on $a$).

Comment: I known this. I wish to be able to directly evaluate it. Just as in the case with $K=+1/a^2$ where $k_g$ is directly calculated and plugged into GB thm to verify it successfully, it is not possible to do so for $ K=-1/a^2$. Right?

Answer (score 3):

Fix $a > 0$. As you've found, in the hyperbolic plane with curvature $-\frac{1}{a^{2}}$, a circle of hyperbolic radius $r$ has geodesic curvature
$$
k_{g} = \tfrac{1}{a} \coth \tfrac{r}{a}.
\tag{*}
$$
The integral is
$$
\int k_{g}\, ds = k_{g} \times \text{perimeter} = 2\pi \cosh \tfrac{r}{a};
$$
since the enclosed total Gaussian curvature is
$$
4\pi \sinh^{2}\tfrac{r}{2a} = 2\pi(\cosh \tfrac{r}{a} - 1),
$$
the Gauss-Bonnet theorem yields the expected result.

---

Here are a couple of ways to see why (*) is true.

First, the geodesic curvature of a circle of intrinsic radius $r$ on a sphere of radius $a$ is $\frac{1}{a} \cot \frac{r}{a}$. On the principle that "corresponding" spherical and hyperbolic quantities are given by corresponding formulas with circular functions replaced by hyperbolic functions, we'd expect the geodesic curvature of a hyperbolic circle of radius $r$ to be $\frac{1}{a} \coth \frac{r}{a}$.

Second (and less magically), model the hyperbolic plane as the open *unit* disk in the Cartesian plane, equipped with the metric
$$
g = \frac{4a^{2}(dx^{2} + dy^{2})}{(1 - (x^{2} + y^{2}))^{2}}.
$$
If $0 \leq R < 1$, the radial segment $(t, 0)$ with $0 \leq t \leq R$ has hyperbolic length
$$
r := \int_{0}^{R} \frac{2\, dt}{a^{2} - t^{2}}
= a\log \frac{a + R}{a - R};
$$
that is, the circle of hyperbolic radius $r$ centered at the origin has Euclidean radius
$$
R = \tanh \tfrac{ar}{2},
\tag{1}
$$
and hyperbolic circumference
$$
\frac{2a(2\pi R)}{1 - R^{2}} = 2\pi a \sinh \tfrac{r}{a}.
$$

To find the geodesic curvature of a circle $C$ of hyperbolic radius $r$, draw the circle of Euclidean radius $R$ centered at the origin, fix a point $p$ of this circle, and draw the hyperbolic line $\ell$ tangent to the circle at $p$. Because $\ell$ is the arc of a Euclidean circle crossing the unit circle at right angles, a bit of geometry shows $\ell$ is part of the Euclidean circle of center $(\frac{1 + R^{2}}{2R}, 0)$ and radius $R' := \frac{1 - R^{2}}{2R}$.

[image: Parallel transport around a hyperbolic circle]

Let $d\theta$ be a small angle at the center of $C$, subtending an arc of hyperbolic length
$$
ds = \frac{2aR}{1 - R^{2}}\, d\theta = a(\sinh \tfrac{r}{a})\, d\theta.
\tag{2}
$$
If $d\phi$ is the indicated Euclidean angle subtended at the Euclidean center of the circle representing $\ell$, then (up to first order in $ds$)
$$
R\, d\theta = R'\, d\phi,\qquad\text{i.e.,}\quad
\frac{d\phi}{d\theta} = \frac{R}{R'} = \frac{2R^{2}}{1 - R^{2}}.
$$
By (1), we have
$$
1 + \frac{d\phi}{d\theta}
= \frac{1 + R^{2}}{1 - R^{2}}
= \frac{1 + \tanh^{2} \frac{r}{2a}}{1 - \tanh^{2} \frac{r}{2a}}
= \cosh \tfrac{r}{a}.
\tag{3}
$$

Parallel transport along $C$ of the boldface tangent vector at $p$ is the vector labeled $v$. The relative angle of turning of the tangent $v'$ to the circle is $d\alpha = d\theta + d\phi$. The geodesic curvature at $p$ is the rate at which the tangent to $C$ rotates per unit length. By (2) and (3), this is equal to
$$
  k_{g} = \frac{d\alpha}{ds}
  = \frac{d\theta + d\phi}{ds} = \left(1 + \frac{d\phi}{d\theta}\right) \frac{d\theta}{ds}
  = \frac{\cosh \frac{r}{a}}{a \sinh \frac{r}{a}} = \tfrac{1}{a} \coth \tfrac{r}{a}.
$$

Comment: At first for physical dimension tally, can I suggest $R=a \tanh \dfrac{r}{2a}, \, (1-R^2) \rightarrow (a^2-R^2)\, etc. $ in the disc model ?

Comment: Yes, the same hyperbolic plane can be modeled using the disk of radius $a$ with the metric$$g = \frac{4a^{2}(du^{2}+ dv^{2})}{(a^{2} - (u^{2} + v^{2}))^{2}}.$$(The mapping $(u, v) = (ax, ay)$ is an isometry with the metric I used.)

Comment: Then are we having ( in the fraction numerator as well as denominator of  first metric $g$  the same $a,1$ representing the same radius? and could it perhaps be changed  throughout ?

Comment: The entire calculation can be expressed in terms of the metric on the disk of radius $a$: hyperbolic quantities won't change (because the two metrics are isometric); "my" Euclidean radius $R$ could be written $R/a$ with $0 \leq R < a$. (In fact, I initially tried to work things out (and type up the results) in the disk of radius $a$. It appears some formulas didn't get converted to the unit disk, thinking specifically of the display before (1).)

Comment: I used symbols $T$ for center circle radius  and $a$ for various hyp. geodesic radii.
 [FullHyperbolicGeodesics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1390096/poincar%C3%A9-hyperbolic-geodesics-in-half-plane-and-disc-models)